# List content type by group name

Tags: sharepoint-2007

```
  SPContentTypeCollection ctc=web.ContentTypes;
  string id = string.Empty;
  foreach (SPContentType item in ctc)
  {
    if (string.Equals(item.Group.ToString(),"Custom CT"))
    {
      id = item.Id.ToString();
      break;
    }
```

Why is the `id = item.id.tostring()` not working. Something's wrong in the if statement.

Comment: can you elaborate what you mean by not working? Are you getting an error or are you just not getting the proper ID?

Comment: Brian, there was a misspelling in "Custom CT ". So the code is good.

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine. There was a misspelling for the CT group name that's why I wasn't getting all the content types for that group.